# Dynamically adjust div height inside another div container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this div (it is a popout side menu) that I have set to 100vh so there is no scrolling.

Inside this popout menu, I have a table of contents and a search field. What I want to do is have the TOC to fill up most of the popout, but when someone searches, the search results div is shown and the TOC adjusts to be smaller than 80vh (what it is now) so that you can see both and you don't need to scroll the bar.

For example, the TOC is 80vh and since nobody has searched for anything, the search container is 0vh (you don't see it). If someone searches for something and the container shows up. I would like it to have a max-height of say 36vh on the search container, and the TOC to have about the same (36vh) so both fill the 100vh container.

How it is now, if I set the TOC container to be 36vh, there is a lot of wasted realestate on the popout that would be nice to have filled with information.

Make sense?

Here's the code:

```
.searchResults  {
overflow-y: auto;
max-height: 36vh;
padding: 15px;
background-color: #ffffff;
border-right: 1px solid;
border-left: 1px solid;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
border-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
font-size: 0.8vw;
}

.panel-body {
padding: 15px;
max-height: 36vh;
overflow-y: auto;
        }
```

And the JavaScript:

```
    <div id="resultsContainer" class="resultsContainer">
        <div id="results"></div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="searchContainer" id="searchContainer">
        <div class="SearchHeading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSearch" title="Collapse / Expand Search Results">
        <svg class="icon-file"><use xlink:href="#icon-file"></use>
        </svg>
Search Results - <font size="1"><i>Click to Collapse / Expand</i></font>
        </a>
        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseSearch" class="searchResults panel-collapse collapse in">
        <ul id="titles" class="nav nav-stacked nav-pills">
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script src="vp/predictiveSearch.js"></script>
        <!-- End of Search Function -->
        <div id="shape-pages" class="panel panel-default" style="display: none">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsePages">
        <svg class="icon-file"><use xlink:href="#icon-file"></use>
        <!-- Collapse Page Note -->
        </svg> Pages - <font size="1"><i>Click to Collapse / Expand</i></font>
        <!-- End Collapse Page Note -->
        </a>
        </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapsePages" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div id="panel-pages" class="panel-body">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: Can you show some code or what have you tried so far and it didnt work ?

Comment: <div id="collapsePages" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div id="panel-pages" class="panel-body">
</div>
</div><div id="collapsePages" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div id="panel-pages" class="panel-body">
</div>
</div>

Comment: CSs:
CSS:
 .searchResults  {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 36vh;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 0.8vw;
  }
  
  .panel-body {
  padding: 15px;
  max-height: 36vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
    }

Comment: <div id="collapseSearch" class="searchResults panel-collapse collapse in">
        <ul id="titles" class="nav nav-stacked nav-pills">
        </ul>
  </div>

Comment: edit your question and post the code there

Comment: <div id="collapseSearch" class="searchResults panel-collapse collapse in">
        <ul id="titles" class="nav nav-stacked nav-pills">
        </ul>
  </div>
</div><div id="collapsePages" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div id="panel-pages" class="panel-body">
</div>
</div>

Comment: You have to edit your question and post the code in the future. I did it for you this time.

Comment: @brentfraser - you can edit the original question to include a Stack Snippet, which makes it really easy for other devs to help answer your question.

Comment: You should also go to jsfiddle.net or codepen.io and create what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified solution using `flex` that allows the search results to take up 50% of the vertical height. The TOC will always fill the remaining space.

Clicking the buttons will add some fake search results to show how the layout adjusts to the content.

```js
/*
/  Only for demo purposes
/  Not needed for the working solution
*/

var btnSearch = document.getElementById("search");
btnSearch.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
  var searchResults = document.getElementById("searchResults");
  searchResults.prepend("Search Results");
});

var btnSearchLong = document.getElementById("searchLong");
btnSearchLong.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");
  var searchResults = document.getElementById("searchResults");
  searchResults.prepend("Search Results Search Results Search Results Search Results Search Results Search Results Search Results Search Results Search Results Search Results Search Results Search Results ");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 200px;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

#searchResults {
  overflow: scroll;
}

#toc {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: pink;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

/*
/  Only for demo purposes
/  Not needed for the working solution
*/

#search {
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  top: 15px;
}

#searchLong {
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
  top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="searchResults"></div>
  <div id="toc">TOC</div>
</div>

<button id="search">Search - Short Results</button>
<button id="searchLong">Search - Long Results</button>
```